# Need to access variable after all ajax call completed

Tags: ajax, jsonp

I setup an ajax call in a loop.

```
 while (true) {


            doAjax("GET", "api", "jsonp");

            if (startDate.valueOf() == endDate.valueOf()) {

                break;
            }

            startDate.setDate(new Date(startDate.getDate() + 1));
        }
```

Where the ajax function is defined as

```
function doAjax(methodType, url, responseDataType) {

    var options = {
        type: methodType,
        url: url,
        dataType: responseDataType,

    };

    $.ajax(options).done(function (data) {

        postData.push(data);

    }).fail(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
};
```

Currently, when all successful call has been made, I finally have an array 'postData' which contain the results of all calls.

Now I am wondering how can I access that variable after all ajax call get's finished. As you can see all happening in the loop, how can I figure out when final ajax call has been made.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to know when the async call completes aside from handling the success (done) or error (fail). So, instead of handling done()/fail() inside of the doAjax() function simply return a promise:

```
return $.ajax(options); //remove the done() and fail() code
```

Then in the function that calls the doAjax function handle the done() and fail().

```
doAjax("GET", "api", "jsonp").done(...).fail(...);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention. I got the point, but as you know all are happening inside a loop. I want to access the Result array when loop and ajax calls complete. How do I find out the last ajax call so, that I will call a function to iterate the result.

Comment: I'd batch up the call first of all and call an endpoint on the server that can handle sending back all of the required data based on a single Ajax call if possible. The looping process would build up an object and then once the loop is completed you would send up the object to the server. You'd then receive back an array or batch type of object. Doing an Ajax call per iteration is something I'd personally avoid if possible.

Otherwise consider batching up the Ajax call options (build up the options for each call in the loop) & possibly use jQuery.when() or similar after the loop completes.

Comment: Thanks for your expert suggestion. I changed my implementation and put responsibility on the server to make multiple async call, when it's done, I simply pass the object to the client to iterate the result.